# Quantitative criteria of Lebesgue Integrability on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ is a Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then a famous results are following : if $f$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
|f(x)| \lesssim \frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha}} \text{ on } x \in B(0;1)^c \quad \text{ for some } \alpha > d,
\end{equation}
then $\int_{B(0;1)^c} |f(x)|dx < \infty$ where $B(0;1)$ is the ball centered at $0$ and radius $1$. However, if
\begin{equation}
|f(x)| \gtrsim \frac{1}{|x|^d} \text{ on } x \in B(0;1)^c,
\end{equation}
then $f$ is not integrable on $B(0;1)^c$.

My question is following. Considering the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|^d \log(x)}$, it is obvious that $|f(x)| < \frac{1}{|x|^d}$ with all sufficiently large $x$ but
\begin{equation}
|f(x)| \geqslant \frac{1}{|x|^{d + \epsilon}}
\end{equation}
with all sufficiently large $x$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. And one can check that $f$ is not integrable on $B(0;1)^c$. I want to know whether there is the critical rate of decay that makes dichotomy between integrability and non-integrability on $B(0;1)^c$. What happens between $1/ \log(x)$ and $1/ |x|^{\epsilon}$ for all $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: No, there is no critical rate of decay.